# Two of my routes are extremely similar, to the point that I copy-pasted most of the stuff. I assume I need to DRY the code but I'm not sure how

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an admin panel route with 2 nested child routes that render 2 views - `AdminBrands` renders brands and allow the admin to see and delete brands, and `AdminCategories` where the admin can see and delete categories. Now the problem is that those 2 views are super similar to each other, but at the same time they have got some differences, so I'm not exactly sure how to DRY them up or even if I should.

The template is mostly the same, with just a couple of small differences. The script part is literally identical, except that the data and functions have different names - `getCategories()` and `getBrands()` for example. Should I try creating some all-mighty view that changes depending on the current route, or stick to having more than 1 components? I've given 2 views as my example, but in my project, I actually have 5 views that are extremely similar, so creating a single view would allow me to remove 4 of them which will make the folder structure a lot cleaner.

```
{
    path: "/admin",
    component: AdminPanel,
    children: [
        {
            path: "categories",
            name: "adminCategories",
            component: AdminCategories
        },
        {
            path: "brands",
            name: "adminBrands",
            component: AdminBrands
        }
    ]
}
```

AdminBrands view:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="admin-brands">
        <div class="column-title">
            <p>Марки</p>
            <div class="create-button" @click="goToCreateBrand()">Добави</div>
        </div>
        <div class="brands">
            <div class="brand" v-for="brand in brands">
                <p>{{ brand.name }}</p>
                <div class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteBrand(brand.id)">Delete</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Pagination :currentPage="currentPage" :totalPages="totalPages" @setCurrentPage="setCurrentPage"></Pagination>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import router from "../../router"
import Pagination from "../Pagination"

export default {
    components: {
        Pagination
    },
    data() {
        return {
            brands: null,
            currentPage: 1,
            totalItems: null,
            totalPages: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getBrands(){
            try {
                let response = await axios.get("/brands?page=" + this.currentPage)

                this.brands = response.data.brands
                this.totalItems = response.data.totalItems
                this.totalPages = response.data.totalPages
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
        async deleteBrand(brandId){
            let response = await axios.post('/deleteBrand', { brandId })

            console.log(response)
        },
        setCurrentPage(page){
            this.currentPage = page
        },
        goToCreateBrand(){
            router.push({ name: "createBrand" })
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getBrands()
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.column-title {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.brand {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.btn {
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

AdminCategories view:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="admin-categories">
        <div class="column-title">
            <p>Категории</p>
            <div class="create-button" @click="goToCreateCategory()">Добави</div>
        </div>
        <div class="categories">
            <div class="category" v-for="category in categories">
                <div class="category-image-container">
                    <img class='category-image' :src="category.image" :alt="category.name">
                </div>
                <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
                <div class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteCategory(category.id)">Delete</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Pagination :currentPage="currentPage" :totalPages="totalPages" @setCurrentPage="setCurrentPage"></Pagination>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import router from "../../router"
import Pagination from "../Pagination"

export default {
    components: {
        Pagination
    },
    data() {
        return {
            categories: null,
            currentPage: 1,
            totalItems: null,
            totalPages: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getCategories(){
            let response = await axios.get("/categories?page=" + this.currentPage)

            this.categories = response.data.categories
            this.totalItems = response.data.totalItems
            this.totalPages = response.data.totalPages
        },
        async deleteCategory(categoryId){
            let response = await axios.post("/deleteCategory", { categoryId })

            console.log(response)
        },
        setCurrentPage(page){
            this.currentPage = page
        },
        goToCreateCategory(){
            router.push({ name: "createCategory" })
        }
    },
    watch: {
        currentPage(){
            this.getCategories()
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getCategories()
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.column-title {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.category {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.category-image-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.category-image {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.btn {
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you can extract common functions (as free function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the best solution is to abstract completely identical (common) functions with [Vue Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) such as `setCurrentPage` and most of your data points `currentPage`, `totalItems` and `totalPages`. Furthermore, you can abstract very similar functions, such as `getCategories`/`getBrands` and `deleteCategory`/`deleteBrand`. Here it's best if you abstract each pair into one function, taking an input whether it's about categories or brands, and then working with them.

Comment: So create a helper js file and put the function which will take input there, and then just import it wherever I need it?

Comment: Yes, but wrap it in a mixin and import it as such, this way all methods are automatically in vue's scope and you can even abstract the variables returned from data this way.